# From where the Mysql history is coming in Workbench?

Tags: mysql

i have observed that workbench has an option called history, which is giving all my db operations in day wise, i want to know from where it is getting, i mean is mysql is maintaining any table internally. I need to update the databse everyday to my client so it will be useful to me, Please help

Answer (score 8):

If anyone still needs this the history is stored (at least in Windows 7) in `UserFolder\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_history` in separate XML files for each day.

Answer (score 4):

For mac users, you can find the history files at

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/sql_history
```

Though the history file stored there only has some dates in it(Seems like Workbench is using it for some indexing.... not sure though). If you need actual history with queries you can check the log files at

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/log/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that regarding this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-history-palette.html the Workbench history is kept from what you acctually execute in the workbench and it is not taking this data from the MySQL server.

Is is a log of queries that you have run in Workbench.

Also "Like the mysql command line client utility, MySQL Workbench has a full history panel, which provides complete session history. This makes it very easy for a user to review, re-run and modify previously executed SQL statement(s). Along with that, multiple queries can be executed at the same time while their results can be viewed in individual tabs. You can also have multiple SQL tabs open at the same time."